# Why does Convert.ToDouble change my Value by factor 1000?

Tags: c#, double, type-conversion

I am reading some x and y coordinates from an XML file.

The coordinates look like this `3.47`, `-1.54`, .. and so on.

When I assign the value to a double variable by

```
double x, y;
x = Convert.ToDouble(reader["X"]); // X Value: 3.47
```

The Value becomes `3470.00`

Why is this the case?

Comment: Wrong culture settings? Try `Convert.ToDouble(reader["x"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others already mentioned, the problem is the culture settings. XML is supposed to work with invariant culture, that's why you should not use `Convert` class (although you can, passing `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in every call, which can easily be forgotten), but a specially provided for that purpose [XmlConvert Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert(v=vs.110).aspx) which covers both writing and reading conversions needed for XML content.

So in your case you should really use

```
x = XmlConvert.ToDouble(reader["X"]);
```

Answer (score 11):

`Convert.ToDouble` method uses your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) settings *by default* if you don't supply *any* `IFormatProvider`.

Looks like your `CurrentCulture` does not use `.` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) but it probably uses as a [`NumberGroupSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator.aspx). That's why your string parsed as `3400` not `3.4`

As a solution, you can use a culture that *already* has `.` as a `NumberDecimalSeparator` in a second parameter of your `Convert.ToDouble` method like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx).

```
double x;
x = Convert.ToDouble("3.47", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // x will be 3.47 not 3470
```

For your `-1.54` example, you need to specify to use combined `AllowLeadingSign` and `AllowDecimalPoint` styles. *Unfortunately*, `Convert.ToDouble` does not have *any* overload which takes `NumberStyles` as a parameter.

For that, you can use `double.Parse` method instead.

```
double x;
x = double.Parse("-1.54", NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,
                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // x will be -1.54
```